# MATLAB - automatically apply obj references in function

Tags: matlab, object

when working with objects in Matlab I constantly have to type

"obj.x, obj.y"

Is there a way to automatically set my matlab functions to apply the obj. reference, so I can just type x and y.

currently i must type as follows:

z = function(obj)
z=obj.x+obj.y

i would like to type
z = function(obj)
z=x+y

Comment: This cannot be done. But I really don’t understand why you would want to do so. Explicitly showing the object you’re indexing makes for much more readable code. If you have to get back to your code a few months later, you’ll be grateful you didn’t try weird shenanigans like what you’re proposing. Also, typing a few characters is too much work?

Answer (score 1):

No. Sorry; this is just how Matlab works; object references are always explicit.